# Crash when using ApplicationShortCut SIGTRAP

Tags: swift, crash, crash-reports

My app crashes immediately when i am trying to use `ApplicationshortcutItem` to navigate to a view controller.
However, my other application shortcut, which goes in 1 `viewcontroller` more does not show this behaviour.
Navigating to the same view controller does work and doesn't make it crash.

My crash:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000010064e5dc 0x100510000 + 1304028
1   PayDay!                         0x000000010011166c 0x1000e0000 + 202348
2   PayDay!                         0x00000001001126a4 0x1000e0000 + 206500
3   UIKit                           0x0000000186c42f40 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 692
4   UIKit                           0x0000000186c430a8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
5   UIKit                           0x0000000186c321a8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360
6   UIKit                           0x0000000186c47b74 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 104
7   UIKit                           0x00000001869d87ac -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
8   UIKit                           0x00000001868e80e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
9   QuartzCore                      0x000000018428ea28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
10  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184289634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
11  UIKit                           0x00000001868fefa4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 924
12  UIKit                           0x00000001869ad57c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1196
13  UIKit                           0x00000001869aaf54 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 228
14  UIKit                           0x00000001869c3cc0 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 728
15  UIKit                           0x00000001869c39ac -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 416
16  UIKit                           0x00000001869c36b4 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 744
17  UIKit                           0x0000000186927b10 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312
18  UIKit                           0x0000000186925d8c +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 324
19  UIKit                           0x00000001869b711c -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 1792
20  UIKit                           0x00000001869acc30 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2696
21  UIKit                           0x00000001869abddc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
22  UIKit                           0x00000001869aba04 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
23  UIKit                           0x00000001869ab96c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
24  UIKit                           0x00000001868e80e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
25  QuartzCore                      0x000000018428ea28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
26  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184289634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
27  QuartzCore                      0x00000001842894f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
28  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184288b24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
29  QuartzCore                      0x000000018428886c CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
30  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184281dd8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817587b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181756554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181680d30 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
34  UIKit                           0x000000018695b834 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
35  UIKit                           0x0000000186955f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
36  PayDay!                         0x00000001001262dc 0x1000e0000 + 287452
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018121e8b8 start + 4
```

Method in `Appdelegate` to show the view controller:

```
if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController, let shortcutItemType = DGShortcutItemType(shortcutItem: shortcutItem) {
            rootViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            switch shortcutItemType {
            case .Message:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let rootTabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
                let firstNav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavController") as! UINavigationController
                rootTabbarController.viewControllers![0] = firstNav
                let VC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeriodeView")
                let VC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("weekViewController")
                let VC3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("timesInsertViewController")
                firstNav.viewControllers.insert(VC1, atIndex: 1)
                firstNav.viewControllers.insert(VC2, atIndex: 2)
                firstNav.pushViewController(VC3, animated: false)
                break
            case .Time:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let rootTabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
                let firstNav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavController") as! UINavigationController
                rootTabbarController.viewControllers![0] = firstNav
                let VC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeriodeView")
                let VC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("weekViewController")
                firstNav.viewControllers.insert(VC1, atIndex: 1)
                firstNav.pushViewController(VC2, animated: false)

                // Display an alert indicating the shortcut selected from the home screen.
                break
            }
        }
```

Note `case .Time` is being run called.

The view shows a tableview and uses a global variable 'pressedYear' which is set on the viewController before navigating to it.
My app delegate also sets this very same variable.

How can  i fix this issue? As i cannot clearly see where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to identify the problem.
As i did not have acces before to my Console (had to kill the app), i changed my scheme and made sure i did have acces to debug tools when starting the app for the first time on UIApplicationShortcut.

i did the following:
i selected my device and clicked 'Edit scheme'
[image]

Which will show you the following result:
[image]

if you press ' Wait for executable to be launched'  u can kill the app entirely and just run it with the debugger attached.

It turned out my application got stuck because a variable got set, but then magically gets set to `""` which made the app crash as it could not convert `""` to an `Int`.
I will have to look into this issue, but for not. It is fixed!